# Use libsvm with OpenCV to predict classes

Tags: opencv, libsvm

I have an SVM RBF Model that was trained using libsvm. I have a feature extractor that is now developed in OpenCV and rather than re-training the model in OpenCV, I want to use the libsvm model directly. I am loading the model using libsvm using svm_load_model. I now want to use svm_predict(model,x) but the test data is to be loaded into svm_node x. How do I convert OpenCV Mat feature to svm_node or for that matter a C++ vector feature to svm_node x?

```
struct svm_node
{
int index;
double value;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

http://book.caltech.edu/bookforum/archive/index.php/t-4065.html

Take a look at this. This has similar problem you (and I ) are facing.

Answer (score -3):

**This link tutorial SVM in OpenCV.**
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html

**You can set SVM parameter. i.e C and G.**
CvSVMParams params;
params.svm_type    = CvSVM::C_SVC;
params.kernel_type = CvSVM::LINEAR;
params.term_crit   = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 1e-6);

**Train SVM model in OpenCV**
CvSVM SVM;
SVM.train(trainingDataMat, labelsMat, Mat(), Mat(), params);

**Finally, you can predict data in SVM model.**
float response = SVM.predict(sampleMat);

Comment: I don't think this is what Sid is asking.